# Bootstrap not working in my custom plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

```
// register jquery and style on initialization
add_action('init', 'register_script');
function register_script() {
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', plugins_url('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', __FILE__));
}
// use the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');
function enqueue_style(){
   wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );
}
```

my folder's name is turnover-calculator it only have the bootrap folder and turnovercalculator.php

i tried to call the btn class to try if it's working but it's still not working.

Comment: when you inspect your frontend, do you see a link with `id="bootstrap-css"` or is there an error.  Also, as noted in the answer by Ali_k which should be correct... you only need to enqueue_style and not use register_style separately, unless you want to enqueue the stylesheet in a specific place only.  As noted in the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/#comment-1650)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the right hooks, `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style` can only be called inside `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook.

please use this code:

```
add_action('init', 'call_scripts');
function call_scripts() {
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');
}


function enqueue_style(){
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap', plugins_url('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just enqueue the style directly inside the `wp_enqueue_scripts` callback like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'turnover_calculator_scripts' );
function turnover_calculator_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', plugins_url('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css', __FILE__));
}
```

Comment: not working form me but thanks man!